Is it necessary to process incoming STOP messages?
I am creating an application that sends basic notifications to users through SMS. Users will sign up through a website, but I would like them to unsubscribe through SMS.
In order to do this, do I need to replace the default webhook for when "A message comes in" from https://demo.twilio.com/welcome/sms/reply to something custom on my end, or can I rely on the default STOP message processing to block messages from being sent to users who have indicated they want to unsubscribe?
As I understand it, the downsides I see to this are within my application I won't have a canonical list of active subscribers, and it sounds like Twilio now charges for all SMS messages sent (even failed ones).
Any guidance on this would be helpful.
Thanks!

Twilio does provide automatic handling for standard opt-out keywords like STOP, UNSUBSCRIBE, and CANCEL, which will block future messages to that number. However, if you'd prefer more control over the process, you can manage opt-outs on your own by configuring a webhook.
With a custom webhook, you can track these opt-out messages in your application, keeping your subscriber list accurate and preventing messages from being sent to users who have opted out. This can also help you avoid unnecessary messaging costs from failed delivery attempts. So, if having a canonical list of active subscribers is important to your app, this option may be a good choice.
